# Sublime Text : Key Binding Regex for a New Line?

Tags: regex, text, binding, key, sublimetext3

I would like to find a new line followed by a `}` character with regex, but I don't think that it only finds the \n(?) :

```
{
  "keys": ["ctrl+m"],
  "command": "run_macro_file",
  "args":
    {"file": "Packages/User/JavaScript/finPointvirguleRetourligne.sublime-macro"}, "context":
    [
      {
        "key": "following_text",
        "operator": "regex_contains",
        "operand": "\n[}]",
        "match_all": true
      }
    ]   
}
```

So

```
"operand": "\n[}]"
```

doesn't work, neither does

```
"operand": "\n"
```

`\n` seems to not mean anything for him in this context with parameter `following_text`

I also find the next expression using `\n(\s)*\{`, which works fine with Ctrl+F in Sublime, but is not accepted in this regex (the file doesn't parse)

**Edit:** this macro is meant to add a semicolon `;` at the end of a line and then go to a new line, but ONLY if there is no '}' in the next line (because I don't want to create a new line otherwise)

Comment: Do you make a typo in the first line? '}' seems to be '{'.BTW, Would you please explain the snippet in ST because not all of us are ST user.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to find \n instead of just using the beginning of line indicator (^)? `^\s*{` should work fine unless you want to combine the two lines when performing a replacement. The `\n` expressions should work just fine if you want to use them though. I've done it plenty of times when modifying XML blocks.

Comment: My probleme is that \n seems don't mean anything for him in this context (with parameter "following_text", etc.). I don't know if it is the good caractere for a "new line" here ? Also because I can't do that : "operand": "\n(\s)*{" -> the json file don't parse...

Comment: @HerringtonDarkholme: yes, my mistake, I edit. Actualy "\n[}]" don't work...

Comment: hmmm...based on your edition I guess `'(?!\})$'` may help. It means find the end of a line where there is no } at the end, so the regex shall match the position where you intend to match. But I do not know what operator nor operand means... probably it doesn't work as I think

Comment: Apparently don't work, but thanks :/ I think it is maybe sublime Text itself the problem, meaning he don't even recognize the \n... I don't know well the option, but "key": "following_text" maybe return only the actual line...

Comment: You might have to double escape the `\n`, like `"\\n[}]`. However, this will only match if there is no whitespace in front of the `}`, so I'd rather use `\\n\\s*[}]`

Comment: Thanks, I think you have right (I didn't understand the double \\\) but unfortunately it always don't work : Sublime don't check the "\\n" ! I think it's simply not possible with the "following_text commande", someone to confirm it please ?

Comment: I couldn't get a newline to be seen using following text either. When the command runs, it likely grabs all of the following text for the current line. I could see some potential performance issues if it tried to grab all of the following text relative to the cursor. Though probably less than ideal, you can emulate the functionality you want with a plugin. There may also be another way, I'm no expert. You can try posting on the ST forums. Though I don't know how likely you are to get a response there. Still worth a try though. Someone might know about a feature that we aren't aware of.